# Best way to start one activity or another basing on a variable

Tags: android

I want to develop an application that, at the beginning, checks a variable's value and, basing on this value, starts the activity A or the activity B, something like this:

```
protectec void onCreate(...){
    boolean b = checkVariable();

    if(b){
        startActivityA();
    } else {
        startActivityb();
    }
}
```

## What I'm doing

This is the method I have currently implemented:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_limitation);

    varChecker = new VarChecker(this);

    if(varChecker.getRemainingUses() <= 0){
        limitReached();
    } else if(varChecker.isFirstTime()){
        firstTime();
    } else {
        startMainActivity();
    }
}
```

This is an activity that must be shown the first time the application is executed. Else, depending on the `getRemainingUses()` result, it must start the activity A or the activity B automatically.

## The question

Is there any way to do what I want, without the need of create a new Activity, specially to avoid the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_limitation)`?

Comment: instead of activities you should use fragments that are to be replaced

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to skip super.onCreate() but you can skip setContentView() and call finish() and return after you start your second Activity

Comment: Take only single activity and based on your calculations, add fragments to this activity. Activity-Fragment is better than Activity-Activity in a sense that your activity will not perform this thing only.

Comment: +1 for using fragments, but if you can't, you can do this check in the main activity, (which you start in the last `else`) so if the case A or B, start either activity and finish the main activity, if it's the last case (else) you don't have to do anything, and this way at least you started an activity (main activity) which could be the one you end-up showing for the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to do what I want, without the need of creating a new
>   Activity, specially to avoid the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
>   and the setContentView(R.layout.activity_limitation)?

I had a similar problem some time ago. As far as I know, It's not possible to avoid calling `super.onCreate(savedInstance)` and `setContentView(R.layout.activity_limitation)`. It's design of the Android activity.

I see the following possible solutions:

1. if you want to choose an appropriate activity by e.g. clicking a
   button, then you just need to create a new Intent basing on a
   variable and there's no problem.
2. if you want to choose an activity in
   a different moment of the flow - e.g. during the application start you can:

   - create a single activity for two options, use fragments and switch between them
   - create "dummy" activity with an empty layout, create an intent and switch to an appropriate activity basing on a variable and finish "dummy" activity. Please note that this solution is a kind of workaround and it's worth to spend some time to figure out something better, but I'm not sure if there is a recommended solution for such use cases.